# "npm install" insall nothing to node_modules folder but a .staging folder centos 7

Tags: node.js, centos

I have this package.json

```
{
  "name": "jangkoo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "keystone": "^0.3.19",
    "async": "^1.5.0",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.3.2",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.9.7", 
    "dotenv": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-config-keystone": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
    "gulp": "^3.7.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4"

  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "node keystone.js"
  }
}
```

When i run npm install, it created a node_modules with a .staging folder inside. No other modules installed. What's the problem here? The OS is Centos 7 .

Answer (score 4):

`npm install` temporarily adds all `node_modules` into a `.staging` folder during install. If something goes wrong during install, like you run out of memory, you could be stuck with this weird `node_modules` install containing the `.staging` folder.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/12540

Answer (score 3):

**for install npm for centos**

```
yum update
```

> yum install npm

Answer (score 1):

I found it out. It failed to install keystone then it stopped. That's why nothing has been installed.

Answer (score 0):

How about remove the node_modules folder and run `npm install` again